# Does `DataFrame.rolling` preserve order in Polars?

Tags: python-polars

Is it safe to re-assign the result of a `DataFrame.rolling` aggregation back into the original dataframe like this:

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "dt": [datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2), datetime(2021, 1, 4), datetime(2021, 1, 5)],
        "key": ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
        "values": pl.arange(0, 4, eager=True),
        "another_column": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bla"],
    }
)

result = (
    df.rolling("dt", period="2d", by="key")
    .agg(
        pl.col("values")
        .sum()
        .alias("the_sum")
    )
)

df = df.select([
    pl.all(),
    result.get_column("the_sum")
])
```

Or should you join `result` back into `df` using the `dt` and `key` columns?

I tried this for a few toy examples, which suggest that `DataFrame.rolling` preserves order, however, this does not guarantee that this is always the case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems not safe to do this. Counter example:

(note that `df` is considered sorted because `check_sorted=True` by default; this is because `df` is sorted *within* groups)

```py
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = (
    pl.DataFrame(
        {
            "dt": [datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2), datetime(2021, 1, 1), datetime(2021, 1, 2)],
            "key": ["a", "a", "b", "b"],
            "values": pl.arange(0, 4, eager=True),
            "another_column": ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bla"],
        }
    )
    .sort("dt", "key")
)

result = df.rolling("dt", period="1d", by="key").agg(pl.col("values").sum().alias("the_sum"))

df = df.select([
    pl.all(),
    result.get_column("the_sum")
])

print(df)  # we expect "values" to be equal to "the_sum"

┌─────────────────────┬─────┬────────┬────────────────┬─────────┐
│ dt                  ┆ key ┆ values ┆ another_column ┆ the_sum │
│ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ ---    ┆ ---            ┆ ---     │
│ datetime[μs]        ┆ str ┆ i64    ┆ str            ┆ i64     │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╪════════╪════════════════╪═════════╡
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ a   ┆ 0      ┆ foo            ┆ 0       │
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ b   ┆ 2      ┆ baz            ┆ 1       │
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ a   ┆ 1      ┆ bar            ┆ 2       │
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ b   ┆ 3      ┆ bla            ┆ 3       │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴────────┴────────────────┴─────────┘
```

Update:

One of the maintainers confirmed on [GitHub](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/12489) that the idiomatic way is to join the result back into the original dataframe. So in this case you should just do:

```py
df.join(result, how="left", on=["dt", "key"])
```

Comment: Thanks for following up. I will leave my answer for now, but I can delete it when you post the idiomatic approach for adding the result back.

Comment: @jqurious OK thanks. Done!