# How to apply a lambda in Python Polars, while grouping by and for a rolling window

Tags: python-polars

With this code and using Pandas, a new column is created while grouping by 2 columns and applying a lambda for a rolling window:

```
lookback_period = 5

df_data = pd.DataFrame(**{
    'columns': ['date', 'close-LDPM', 'ticker', 'timeframe'],
    'data': [
        ['31/12/2021', 10.87, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['07/01/2022', 11.04, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['14/01/2022', 11.36, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['21/01/2022', 11.01, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['28/01/2022', 12.07, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['04/02/2022', 12.44, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['11/02/2022', 12.38, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['18/02/2022', 10.06, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['25/02/2022', 10.12, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['04/03/2022', 8.1, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['11/03/2022', 8.45, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['18/03/2022', 9.05, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['25/03/2022', 9.27, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['01/04/2022', 9.51, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['08/04/2022', 9.66, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['14/04/2022', 8.49, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['22/04/2022', 8.53, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['29/04/2022', 7.96, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['06/05/2022', 7.71, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['13/05/2022', 7.65, 'ERIC', '1 W'],
        ['20/05/2022', 7.77, 'ERIC', '1 W']
    ]
})

df_data['LDPS_w'] = (
    df_data.groupby(['ticker', 'timeframe'], group_keys=False)['close-LDPM']
    .rolling(window=lookback_period)
    .apply(lambda x: pd.Series(sum(x[-i] / i for i in range(1, lookback_period + 1))), raw=True)
    .reset_index(level=[0, 1], drop=True)
)

print(df_data)
```

with output:

```
    date  close-LDPM ticker timeframe     LDPS_w
0   31/12/2021       10.87   ERIC       1 W        NaN
1   07/01/2022       11.04   ERIC       1 W        NaN
2   14/01/2022       11.36   ERIC       1 W        NaN
3   21/01/2022       11.01   ERIC       1 W        NaN
4   28/01/2022       12.07   ERIC       1 W  26.295667
5   04/02/2022       12.44   ERIC       1 W  27.193000
6   11/02/2022       12.38   ERIC       1 W  27.647833
7   18/02/2022       10.06   ERIC       1 W  25.616167
8   25/02/2022       10.12   ERIC       1 W  24.800667
9   04/03/2022        8.10   ERIC       1 W  22.096333
10  11/03/2022        8.45   ERIC       1 W  20.864333
11  18/03/2022        9.05   ERIC       1 W  20.517000
12  25/03/2022        9.27   ERIC       1 W  20.660667
13  01/04/2022        9.51   ERIC       1 W  20.894167
14  08/04/2022        9.66   ERIC       1 W  21.457500
15  14/04/2022        8.49   ERIC       1 W  20.617500
16  22/04/2022        8.53   ERIC       1 W  20.226500
17  29/04/2022        7.96   ERIC       1 W  19.372000
18  06/05/2022        7.71   ERIC       1 W  18.587833
19  13/05/2022        7.65   ERIC       1 W  17.988833
20  20/05/2022        7.77   ERIC       1 W  17.861000
```

How could the above be expressed with Polars?

what I have tried so far (with some CoPilot help) is the following:

```
def weighted_avg(series: pl.Series) -> float:
    n = len(series)
    weights = pl.Series([1 / i for i in range(1, n + 1)])
    return (series * weights).sum() / weights.sum()

# Apply the function to the rolling window of the 'close-LDPM' column
df_data['LDPS_w'] = (
    df_data.groupby(['ticker', 'timeframe'], group_keys=False)
    .select(pl.col('close-LDPM'))
    .rolling_apply(weighted_avg, window=lookback_period, min_periods=1, center=False))
```

but, naturally I get

> AttributeError: 'GroupBy' object has no attribute 'select'

Comment: I think you could improve this question by adding a small amount of example data, the output you expect with that sample data, what you've tried in polars already, and where you're encountering issues

Comment: happy to provide an answer if you make a reproducible example, please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thank you both for your comments and patience as this is my first attempt to a stack overflow question. I hope my edited version is at the required standards

Comment: @ignoring_gravity

Comment: thanks, this is close - instead of posting a screenshot, can you just copy-and-paste the dataframe?

Comment: table added @ignoring_gravity

Comment: getting closer - if you could make it copy-and-pasteable that would really help speed up writing a solution https://matthewrocklin.com/minimal-bug-reports.html

Comment: I used `df_data.to_dict(index=False, orient='split')` to get the "dict" for the pandas dataframe which I edited in to your example (there are other ways). Providing the "code" for the dataframe is usually what is meant instead of just providing the "repr". With just the "repr" we have to copy it, fix the broken line and use `pd.read_clipboard()` which is quite awkward. Feel free to edit it further in your own way. (It was just simpler for me to show than try to explain it all in a comment) You may want to add in an example with a value for `lookback_period` and showing the output.

Comment: quite the educative experience and thank you all for your guidance and time. @jqurious, I think I got it right this time?

Comment: Yes, that looks spot on. Your code example is now runnable.

Answer (score 1):

There is a dedicated [`.rolling()`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.rolling.html) method to perform the group_by/rolling operation.

You can then perform your calculations inside the `.agg()` context.

```py
lookback_period = 5

window = dict(
   by = ("ticker", "timeframe"),               # group_by these columns
   index_column = pl.int_range(0, pl.count()), # a "row count" to use as the index
   period = f"{lookback_period}i"              # window "size"
)

df.rolling(**window).agg(
   pl.when(pl.count() == lookback_period)
     .then(
        (pl.col("close-LDPM")
         / (pl.col("close-LDPM").cum_count().reverse() + 1)).sum()
     )
)
```

```py
shape: (21, 4)
┌────────┬───────────┬─────┬────────────┐
│ ticker ┆ timeframe ┆ int ┆ close-LDPM │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---        │
│ str    ┆ str       ┆ i64 ┆ f64        │
╞════════╪═══════════╪═════╪════════════╡
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 0   ┆ null       │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 1   ┆ null       │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 2   ┆ null       │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 3   ┆ null       │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 4   ┆ 26.295667  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 5   ┆ 27.193     │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 6   ┆ 27.647833  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 7   ┆ 25.616167  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 8   ┆ 24.800667  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 9   ┆ 22.096333  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 10  ┆ 20.864333  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 11  ┆ 20.517     │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 12  ┆ 20.660667  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 13  ┆ 20.894167  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 14  ┆ 21.4575    │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 15  ┆ 20.6175    │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 16  ┆ 20.2265    │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 17  ┆ 19.372     │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 18  ┆ 18.587833  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 19  ┆ 17.988833  │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 20  ┆ 17.861     │
└────────┴───────────┴─────┴────────────┘
```

#### Notes

Then `when/then` condition is used to `null` out the smaller windows.

The reverse `cum_count` is one way to emulate the `range()` behaviour in your example.

```py
df.rolling(**window).agg(
   value = pl.col("close-LDPM"),
   weight = pl.col("close-LDPM").cum_count().reverse() + 1
)
```

```py
shape: (21, 5)
┌────────┬───────────┬─────┬─────────────────────────────────────┬─────────────────┐
│ ticker ┆ timeframe ┆ int ┆ value                               ┆ weight          │
│ ---    ┆ ---       ┆ --- ┆ ---                                 ┆ ---             │
│ str    ┆ str       ┆ i64 ┆ list[f64]                           ┆ list[u32]       │
╞════════╪═══════════╪═════╪═════════════════════════════════════╪═════════════════╡
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 0   ┆ [10.87]                             ┆ [1]             │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 1   ┆ [10.87, 11.04]                      ┆ [2, 1]          │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 2   ┆ [10.87, 11.04, 11.36]               ┆ [3, 2, 1]       │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 3   ┆ [10.87, 11.04, 11.36, 11.01]        ┆ [4, 3, 2, 1]    │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 4   ┆ [10.87, 11.04, 11.36, 11.01, 12.07] ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 5   ┆ [11.04, 11.36, 11.01, 12.07, 12.44] ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 6   ┆ [11.36, 11.01, 12.07, 12.44, 12.38] ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 7   ┆ [11.01, 12.07, 12.44, 12.38, 10.06] ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 8   ┆ [12.07, 12.44, 12.38, 10.06, 10.12] ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 9   ┆ [12.44, 12.38, 10.06, 10.12, 8.1]   ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 10  ┆ [12.38, 10.06, 10.12, 8.1, 8.45]    ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 11  ┆ [10.06, 10.12, 8.1, 8.45, 9.05]     ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 12  ┆ [10.12, 8.1, 8.45, 9.05, 9.27]      ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 13  ┆ [8.1, 8.45, 9.05, 9.27, 9.51]       ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 14  ┆ [8.45, 9.05, 9.27, 9.51, 9.66]      ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 15  ┆ [9.05, 9.27, 9.51, 9.66, 8.49]      ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 16  ┆ [9.27, 9.51, 9.66, 8.49, 8.53]      ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 17  ┆ [9.51, 9.66, 8.49, 8.53, 7.96]      ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 18  ┆ [9.66, 8.49, 8.53, 7.96, 7.71]      ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 19  ┆ [8.49, 8.53, 7.96, 7.71, 7.65]      ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
│ ERIC   ┆ 1 W       ┆ 20  ┆ [8.53, 7.96, 7.71, 7.65, 7.77]      ┆ [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] │
└────────┴───────────┴─────┴─────────────────────────────────────┴─────────────────┘
```

#### Multiple columns

Assuming all columns follow a similar naming pattern we can:

- [select all `close-` columns by regex](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/expressions/column-selections/#by-regular-expressions) to process them all together.
- use [`.name.map`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/docs/python/dev/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.map.html#polars.Expr.name.map) to extract the final part of the column name and add the `_w` suffix.
- use regex again to select the newly created `_w` columns.

```py
weighted_sums = (
   df.with_columns(pl.col("close-LDPM").reverse().alias("close-ABCD")) # add dummy column
     .rolling(**window).agg(
        pl.when(pl.count() == lookback_period)
          .then(
           (pl.col("^close-.+$") # select all `close-` columns
            / (pl.col("^close-.+$").cum_count().reverse() + 1)).sum()
        )
        .name.map(lambda col: col.rsplit('-', 1)[1] + "_w") # extract everything after last `-` and add `_w` suffix
   )
   .select("^.+_w$") # select all `_w` columns
)
```

```py
shape: (21, 2)
┌───────────┬───────────┐
│ LDPM_w    ┆ ABCD_w    │
│ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ f64       ┆ f64       │
╞═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      │
│ null      ┆ null      │
│ 26.295667 ┆ 18.5465   │
│ 27.193    ┆ 18.865833 │
│ 27.647833 ┆ 20.280333 │
│ 25.616167 ┆ 20.8945   │
│ 24.800667 ┆ 21.0735   │
│ 22.096333 ┆ 20.968    │
│ 20.864333 ┆ 20.3745   │
│ 20.517    ┆ 19.561167 │
│ 20.660667 ┆ 21.103167 │
│ 20.894167 ┆ 21.7425   │
│ 21.4575   ┆ 24.498333 │
│ 20.6175   ┆ 26.133333 │
│ 20.2265   ┆ 26.955667 │
│ 19.372    ┆ 26.298667 │
│ 18.587833 ┆ 26.474333 │
│ 17.988833 ┆ 25.8955   │
│ 17.861    ┆ 25.343167 │
└───────────┴───────────┘
```

#### Add result back to original dataframe

In this case (with a "row count" index) the order is guaranteed, so we can simply `.with_columns` to add the result.

```py
df = df.with_columns(weighted_sums)
```

Otherwise, you would a join: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77489932

Comment: thank you very much for the detailed response!

one detail if I may ask. I need this to be a new and separate column [LDPS_w], while keeping the original dataframe and the initial [close-LDPM] column.

how can I achieve that?

Comment: @iKiok I've updated with an example of multiple columns - in this case the order is guaranteed, so you can just select out the new columns and `.with_columns` them back into the original.

Comment: thank you @jqurious, great help. I have also provided my final solution

Answer (score 0):

final code with the invaluable help from @jqurious:

```
df_data = df_data.with_columns([pl.col("close-LDPM").alias("LDPS_w")])
window = dict(
by = ("ticker", "timeframe"),               # group_by these columns
index_column = pl.int_range(0, pl.count()), # a "row count" to use as the index
period = f"{lookback_period}i"              # window "size"
)

weighted_sums = df_data.rolling(**window).agg(
pl.when(pl.count() == lookback_period)
    .then(
        (pl.col("LDPS_w")
        / (pl.col("LDPS_w").cum_count().reverse() + 1)).sum()
    )
)

df_data = df_data.with_columns(weighted_sums)
df_data = df_data.drop(["int"])
```

I duplicated the column "close-LDPM" that I wanted to run the weighted average on, so I got to keep the original column and the new one.

Thanx again @jqurious